# Google Picker API -- Button click event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-picker

I would like to know how to load the Google Drive Picker window after a user clicks on a button.

I easily implemented Dropbox's Chooser API with the code provided on their website.

Now, the following "Hello World" application code, provided by Google at https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/index, did not work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'xxxxxxxYYYYYYYY-12345678';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
      var clientId = "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com"

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,
              'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        }
        var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added my API key and Client ID, and then, instead of `<div id="result">` at the bottom, I tried to apply the code on a Bootstrap button, with `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="result">` and it didn't work.

My question is: Is there a better example of Google Picker's API working on a button click?

Comment: Make sure you've loaded the bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js already and here's a good example for this kind of issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094430/how-to-show-the-google-picker-api-dialog-after-user-presses-a-button-or-an-image?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the following for google drive picker?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<button  id="googleDrive" onClick="onApiLoad(); return false;" value="G_driver">Google Drive</button>
```